# what is used to display a successful message after filling out a form that displays previously filled data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I know about flash message from Laravel. But, i want to display data that has been filled as succesful message. 
I thought about redirect it with max id query for calling the data, but it can  be accessed anytime by typing it on address bar. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So you can use this for bootstrap in your blade file

```
@if(session('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('success') }}
  </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ session('error') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

For Bulma you can use

```
@if(session('success'))
  <div class="notification is-success">
    {{ session('success') }}
  </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
  <div class="notification is-danger">
    {{ session('error') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

In your controller you do ex

```
return redirect('/home')->withSuccess('success message');
```

or

```
return redirect('/home')->withError('error message');
```

If you want it to be removed after a couple of seconds you need to implement some javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach if it solves your problem. Otherwise please provide your code to check what you want to do.

```
$name= "John";
return redirect()->route('routename')->with('success',"Thanks for you feedback ".$name);
```